# How to process __VA_ARGS__ in C++ preprocessing?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, boost-preprocessor

```
#define INITIALIZE_INT_ARRAY(elem_type, array_name,...) \
    elem_type array_name[] = { __VA_ARGS__ }; \ 

INITIALIZE_INT_ARRAY(int, arr, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
// will expand to
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4. 5};
```

Now I want to support tuples in `__VA_ARGS__` and will simply take the first element of the tuple if it is a tuple.

```
INITIALIZE_INT_ARRAY(int, arr, 1, (2, hello), (3, world), (4, X), 5)
// will still expand to
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

How can I change my `INITIALIZE_INT_ARRAY`?

Comment: I'm adding c++ tag to make this question reach more people.

Answer (score 0):

In general, iterating over comma-separate lists in preprocessor requires writing `O(n)` boilerplate macros. You can write yourself or get them from Boost.Preprocessor, or...

You can use a different syntax for the list: `FOO(int, arr, (1)(2, hello)(3, world)(4, X)(5))`.

Then the macro can be written like this, without boilerplate:

```
#define FOO(type_, name_, seq_) \
    type_ name_[] = { FOO_END( FOO_LOOP_A seq_ ) }; \
    
#define FOO_END(...) FOO_END_(__VA_ARGS__)
#define FOO_END_(...) __VA_ARGS__##_END
    
#define FOO_LOOP_A(...) FOO_LOOP_BODY(__VA_ARGS__,) FOO_LOOP_B
#define FOO_LOOP_B(...) FOO_LOOP_BODY(__VA_ARGS__,) FOO_LOOP_A
#define FOO_LOOP_A_END
#define FOO_LOOP_B_END

#define FOO_LOOP_BODY(x, ...) x,
```